# Mediafront Youtube playlist feed playlist problem

Tags: 7, media, files

I installed the MediaFront 7.x-2.0-rc2 module and MediaFront: Youtube Playlist Feeds 7.x-2.0-rc2.

I want a player with the playlist on the side.  The feed imports fine and creates the nodes.  In my player, I have the video, but for the playlist, I have blank videos, each with a "Sample Title" title.  When I click on a blank video, it correctly plays the video in the main player, so the view knows about the other videos.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I thought I answered this.  Sorry!  I figured out the problem was I didn't have thumbnail pics enabled.  I thought I didn't need to since I didn't have accompanying thumbnail images, but it still is required to fill the thumbnails with the title and video still.

Answer (score 2):

this i found useful: https://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

which got me a functioning feed URL for MediaFront and so I still can create a playlist as a MediaFront preset. But its still another problem, yet to be solved, to get that MediaFront YouTube playlist preset to show as a node!!

Because when I add the same URL into an empty preset, its fails, complaining URL is bad!!

good luck and let me know how it goes for you ;-)

Richard